# Forward declaration and destructors

Tags: c++, oop, destructor, forward-declaration

Imagine the simple class line segment which it's constructor is are couple of objects from the class point:

```
class Point ;

class LineSegment {
    public:

      LineSegment(Point* P1, Point* P2);
      ~LineSegment();
} ;
```

The question is, in the destructor, should I delete the points first or it will be done automatically? On the other words, in the cpp file, which of the following should be written:

```
LineSegment::~LineSegment()
```

or

```
LineSegment::~LineSegment(){
     delete P1;
     delete P2;
}
```

Comment: The first one will work, too. It just depends what you want. If the `Point`s are owned by someone else (e.g. a `std::vector`) you'll have a crash of the "don't understand why, it must work" kind later. The class declaration does not show the `Point`s as class members, so...

Comment: @Damon we can assume they are members and he just left them out. How else could he call them in the destructor?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Good point about the declaration. Though of course it still necessarily doesn't imply that the class actually owns the pointed-to `Point` objects (and thus is allowed to delete them). Having "points" and "lines", a very valid and efficient approach (think of transforming them, not just allocation) is to store the points in an array or vector, and reference them from the line objects (not owning them).

Comment: @Damon I'm not saying it owns them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, note that

```
LineSegment::~LineSegment(){
     ~P1();
     ~P2();
}
```

is invalid. To delete, you need `delete P1` and `delete P2`.

Also, figure out who owns `P1` and `P2`. If they are owned by the class, delete them in the destructor, but note that you won't be able to access them outside after the object is destroyed.

So, for example:

```
Point* p1 = new Point;
Point* p2 = new Point;

{
   LineSegment l(p1,p2);
}

delete p1;
delete p2;
```

Would be illegal if you `delete` the pointers in the destructor.

Either version you choose, be sure to **document** your decision - i.e. **make it clear whether the class assumes ownership of the pointers or not**.

You wouldn't have this problem if you'd use **smart pointers**.

Comment: Thanks. But apart from my syntactical error, should I remove the points first or they are deleted automatically when i delete the line object?

Comment: @Pouya if you allocate them with `new` or `malloc`, they are not deleted automatically. But the question is - do you delete them outside the class anywhere? Or does the class have ownership? I'm thinking you either didn't read or didn't understand my answer.

Answer (score 2):

To delete them, you have to use the delete operator, that way:

```
LineSegment::~LineSegment(){
     delete P1;
     delete P2;
}
```

Doing that will call the destructor of P1 and P2

The only way to have the points deleted automatically would be to have them by value as member of the class:

```
class LineSegment {
protected:
    Point P1;
    Point P2;
public:
    /* constructors and destructors */
};
```

By doing that, when LineSegment is deleted, P1 and P2 will be destroyed automatically.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Yes, but in that case the points won't be be deleted when the destructor is called, they will be deleted when there will be no more smart pointers on them.

Comment: And that's bad because...? If multiple LineSegments hold the same Points, then that's a good thing, whereas using objects (like in your code) is wasteful in terms of memory (you're duplicating identical points).

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I am not saying that's bad, it just seems that the question was about deleting the points when `LineSegment` is destroyed.